# Remove substring after the second dot in a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL from which I want to remove the substring after the second dot.

input:

```
google.com/xyz.abc.html
```

output:

```
google.com/xyz
```

The following regex works, but not sure this is the right way to do it

```
^([\w/]+\.[\w/]+\.)
```

Comment: Replace `[\w/]+` with `[^.]+` or `[^.]*`. You probably do not need to capture the second `\.`, too, `^[^.]+\.[^.]+(?=\.)` might be what you need

Comment: Where do you get the url from? Is it from `location`?

Comment: @Gh05d No, I don't get it from location. It is a string from the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use split and join, 2nd argument inside split is to limit the number of chunks, i.e here it will only output 2 element in resulting array

```js
console.log(`google.com/xyz.abc.html`.split('.',2).join('.'))
```

Comment: This does not work in case of a domain starting with `www` or a sub-domain or a website having domain name `.com.xx` e.g. `www.google.com, subdomain.google.com, google.com.pt`. It can work with a simple domain name like in the example so that the second `.` character is in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non regex solution for this.

```js
let inp = 'google.com/xyz.abc.html';
let out = [inp.split('/')[0], inp.split('/')[1].split('.')[0]].join('/');
console.log(out);
```